# SFMC Is there any way we can have tracking results in Journey from Journey in SFMC to sales cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, email-tracking, tracking

If I am using Journey builder for email communications, How can I track results in sales cloud from Journey Builder. Is there any feature which needs to be enabled?